# Как скопировать текст из списка QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qlistwidget

Я создал список в `QListWidget` с названиями файлов, и хочу сделать возможность копирования названия по клику мыши.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте код, который вы уже написали, т.е. минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

> void QListWidget::**itemClicked**(QListWidgetItem *item)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается с указанным элементом, когда кнопка мыши нажимается на элемент в виджете.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


def formatColor(text, color):
    return '<font color={0}>{1}</font>'.format(color.name(), text)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.onItemClicked)

        self.resultView = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.resultView.setReadOnly(True)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.resultView)

        self.initData()

    def initData(self):
        # Инициализировать данные
        for i in range(100):
            item = QListWidgetItem('Item {0}'.format(i), self.listWidget)

    def onItemClicked(self, item):
        self.resultView.appendHtml(
            '{0}: {1}'.format(
                formatColor('itemClicked', QColor(Qt.magenta)), 
                item.text()
            )
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]